# How to prevent a root class checking with Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

Here is my question. I have a simple test code.

```
public interface CommandFactory {
    public <T extends Command> T createCommand(Class<T> commandClass);
}
class Test implements CommandFactory {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Test test = new Test();
        test.createCommand(Command.class); // not valid case. should stop this action by compiler
    }    
    @Override
    public <T extends Command> T createCommand(Class<T> commandClass) {
        return commandClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I pass a root type `Command`. But I want to prevent this. What I want is to pass to `createCommand` method only children of `Command`.

The correct case is to pass `MyCommand` class which extends a `Command`, for instance.

Is is possible is Java?

*PS*

```
public abstract class AbstractCommand implements Command {
    // ...
}
```

The solution with AbstractCommand class is unsuitable, because I need to check additionally the type of command. And If I don't do that I'll get `InstantiationException` when pass `AbstractCommand.class`.

Comment: Can you make `AbstractCommand` package private, instead of `public`, so that it is not accessible outside, and thus lowers the risk of passing that as argument. That also means, you would have to keep factories in the same package. I guess I would go with explicit condition check approach here.

Answer (score 4):

You can't enforce such restrictions using generics. The best you can do is, to do a type check inside method, and throw exception if `Command.class` is received as argument. Even more, add documentation comment for that scenario:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param cl
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *           when type of cl is Command.class
 * @return
 */
public <T extends Command> T createCommand(Class<T> cl) {
  if (cl == Command.class) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can only accept subclasses of Command");
  }
  return null;
}
```

Better would be to add documentation comment to interface method, so that any implementing class knows about the contract.

Another approach, if feasible in your case, can be to introduce an abstract class in between `Command` and `MyCommand`, and change the bounds accordingly:

```
class Command {
}

abstract class AbstractCommand extends Command {
}

class MyCommand extends AbstractCommand {
}
```

so, all your sub-commands would now extend `AbstractCommand` instead of `Command`. And then, your interface would be like:

```
public interface CommandFactory {
    public <T extends AbstractCommand> T createCommand(Class<T> cl);
}
```

and then, you can't pass a `Command.class` to it. But I don't think this will solve the concrete problem you're trying to solve (which we really don't know what it is), because now you can pass `AbstractCommand.class` to the method. You can play with the visibility of `AbstractCommand` though, as you're not going to use it else-where.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution. But I don't want to deal with checking type in if block. I'm interesting only in generic solution.

Comment: @barbara There is no other way, I'm afraid.

Comment: @barbara If you've to do it that way, you can introduce a dummy interface - `AbstractCommand` between `Command` super interface, `MyCommand` type. And then change the bound of `T` to `<T extends AbstractCommand>`

Comment: Hmm. `createCommand` seems to be intended for being overridden. So the check will be overridden with it. Perhaps there should be a `public final createCommand()` and a `protected createCommandImpl()` that should be overridden, and the public one calls and checks the protected one?